# How to use Left Join sql query result into a model gridview in yii

Tags: php, sql, gridview, yii

This is the code,

```
$model=new Tblvehicle;

$sql="Select tblvehicle.serial_no, tblmodel.description, tbluser.user_name, tbluser.user_code "
    . "From tblvehicle"
    . " left join tblmodel "
    . "on tblvehicle.model_code= tblmodel.model_code"
    . " left join tbluser"
    . " on tblvehicle.user_code=tbluser.user_code"; 
$query= Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sql)->queryScalar();
$dataProvider = new CSqlDataProvider($sql, array('totalItemCount'=>$query));

$this->render('index',array(
   'model'=>$model,'dataProvider'=> $dataProvider));
```

and this is my incomplete `Tblvehicle` grid view -

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
              'id'=>'tblvehiclegrid',
              'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
              'filter'=>$model,
              'columns'=>array(
```

Now how can I show those 4 columns `serial_no, description, user_name,` and `user_code`? Because these came from different tables, I don't know how to add them in.

```
'columns'=>array(
```

Maybe the way I am trying to do it is also wrong. So please need some help in this, I am very new to Yii.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the necessary controller code

```
$criteria=new CDbCriteria();
$dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('Tblvehicle', array(
                                                    'criteria'=>$criteria,
                                                    'pagination'=>array(
                                                        'pageSize'=>5,
                                                        ),
                                        ));

return $dataProvider;

$this->render('index',array(
'model'=>$model,'dataProvider'=> $dataProvider));
```

Add the following lines to the relationship section of the Tblvehicle model to look like so, only use two of the 4 relationships, read why in the code comments

```
public function relations()
{
    // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
    // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
    return array(


        'rl_model'=>array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Tblmodel', 'model_code'),//presuming that model_code is the primary key of this table if not use the two below
        'rl_user'=>array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Tbluser', 'user_code'),//presuming that user_code is the primary key of this table if not use the two below

        'rl_model' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Tblmodel', '', 'foreignKey' => array('model_code'=>'model_code')), //Non Primary field
        'rl_user' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Tbluser', '', 'foreignKey' => array('user_code'=>'user_code')), //Non Primary field
    );
}
```

Then use this in the view

```
    'columns'=>array(
                    'serial_no',
                    'subject',
                    array(
                        'name'=>'Description Code',
                        'value'=>'$data->rl_model->description',
                    ),

                    array(
                        'name'=>'Username',
                        'value'=>'$data->rl_user->user_name',
                    ),
                    array(
                        'name'=>'User Code',
                        'value'=>'$data->rl_user->user_code',
                    ),

                ),
```

Basically rather than having to write mysql statements and using joins, we can effectively create the join using a relationship. This field can then be referenced any time as shown in the above.

Let me know how you get on.

Comment: Thnx a lot Mr. Was going crazy about this. It is working now. Only a small correction. Instead of 'name' i think we need to use 'header'.

Comment: @Farhad No problem. The reason I was using `name` actually is because you can't sort your custom columns without some more fiddling. This post http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/8784-cgridview-sort-columns/page__p__232077#entry232077 will show you how to sort them if you need this. But your are correct in your circumstances `header` is the way. Glad I could help.